# .htaccess redirect all traffic to domain but few hand written exceptions

Tags: .htaccess

How to redirect traffic from `www.old.com` to `www.new.com` but

- `www.old.com/hello` to `www.new.com/byebye`
- `www.old.com/test?start=5` to `www.new.com/page/site`

I have this to start with:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /

# root
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^www\.(([^\.]+))\.pl [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://%1.pl%{REQUEST_URI} [R=301,L]

# Redirect
Redirect permanent old.com/hello new.com/byebye
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use this .htaccess:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /

# redirect
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^www\.old\.com$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^hello$ http://www.new.com/byebye [NC,R=301,L]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^www\.old\.com$ [NC]
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} ^start=5$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^test$ http://www.new.com/page/site? [NC,R=301,L]

# root
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^www\.([^.]+)\.pl [NC]
RewriteRule ^ http://%1.pl%{REQUEST_URI} [R=301,L]
```